# Syncing to a database behind a gateway

Tags: mysql, replication

On our network we have a tunnel to a NAT gateway host.  From the gateway host we are able to access a private network.  On this network we will be running jobs that log to a database.  The database will be hosted on the same network.

A couple of notes on the remote database:

1. The database will only receive lightweight insert/update queries when a job starts/finishes.  At peak usage this could be 10 queries/minute, but it would probably average closer to 0-1 queries/minute.
2. The database probably won't be run from the gateway host, but it could share a file system (so log files may be accessible from the gateway host).

We would like to continuously sync data from the remote database to a local MySQL database (remote database is not configured yet but it will probably be MySQL).  The sync should be close to real time, but a 5-10 minute delay is acceptable.

How can we achieve this?  I don't know anything about DBA/networking but it seems like one way to do this would be to set up a cron job to pull log files from the gateway host, then perform an update to the local database based on the logs.  Am I on the right track?  Is there anything else that I need to consider/look in to?